# javascript - split array into multiple page index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have a function called Render(arr). Arr is a parameter that contain 50 rows of data.
I have an empty div in html page

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

when I use this javascript code

```
var s=""
for(i<0;i<arr.length;i++{
    s+= arr[i].attr1.toString();
    s+= arr[i].attr2.toString();
    s+= arr[i].attr3.toString();
}
var data = document.getElementById("test");
data.innerHTML = s;
```

It will render all the 50 rows of data along with the attributes in a html page which is space-consuming.
How to make page indexing if i want to split the array into page indexing that a page only contain 5 data? e.g. page 1 only show data row 1-5, page 2 only show data row 6-10 without refreshing the page?

thanks

Comment: can you make a fiddle

Comment: You're looking for Pagination. I'd suggest using a plugin like this: http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/

Comment: @Newtt oh I dont know the term of pagination. +1 Thanks for mentioning it

Answer (score 0):

```
var page = curr_page - 1;
for(i=page*5;i<page*5+5;i++{
    s+= arr[i].attr1.toString();
    s+= arr[i].attr2.toString();
    s+= arr[i].attr3.toString();
}
```

Something like this?

if curr_page = 1
the for will loop 5 times, from 0 to 5

if its 2 it will loop from 5 to 10
and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = current_page * 5 - 5, j = 0; j < 5; j++, i++) {
  s += arr[i].attr1.toString();
  s += arr[i].attr1.toString();
  s += arr[i].attr1.toString();
}
```